# How to get email id of authenticated user in Azure App service with Laravel APP

Tags: laravel, azure-web-app-service

I have a Laravel application which I want to host on Azure App Service.
I added Azure Active directory Authentication, it works well

Now I want to get email Id and user name (Just Name) for a logged in user. So I can display the email and log the activities of that user.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure pass user information in the header
Laravel has built in method to get header information

```
$headers = getallheaders();
```

Get email from

```
[X-Ms-Client-Principal-Name] => email@example.com
```

Get User Name and other information by jwt token

```
[X-Ms-Client-Principal]
```

You can check what does your token consists of on https://jwt.io/